# Is there a way to group multiple blocks into one block in step functions

Tags: aws-step-functions

I want to include logic that will valid date the input object's keys and values in a step functions. This will result in a bloated step functions workflow that comprises too many choice blocks. Is there a way I can group these blocks into one in step functions?

I tried implement the validation checks with choice blocks in step functions, but they are too many and lead to a bloated step functions. I want to avoid wrapping the choice blocks into their own step functions.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a native solution, but i am a big fan of [middy js](https://middy.js.org/). Middy lets you build lambdas thru the chaining of middleware. There is a [middleware for schema validation](https://middy.js.org/docs/middlewares/validator), you could implement the validation in a schema and let the middy lambda validate the input and return either an error or the valid state.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the block a state machine and your master state machine just call that state machine as a step. That will make your master state machine definition cleaner.

This is an example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sample-start-workflow.html

An alternative is to consider moving the logic inside your lambda functions so the branches after the validation happens in the same lambda function.